# Doctrine2 How to compare two result sets

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, intersection

I have two entities: `Category` and `Icon` they have a many to many relationship so i end up with three tables: `category` `icon` and `icon_category`

My goal is to find Icons that are in multiple categories.

For example I have the following

categories: `a` `b` `c` and icons `1` `2` `3`

Here are the categories for the icons:

`1` - `a` `b`

`2` - `a`

`3` - `c`

I would like to search for an icon that is in category `a` and `b` and get `1` as the result.

My first approach was to load in each category (`a` and `b`) into separate results and then compare using `array_intersect()`:

```
  $cats = array();

  foreach($terms as $term){
      $cat = $em->getRepository('SixStringPearBundle:Category')->findOneBy(array("name" => $term));
      if($cat){
         $cats[$term] = $cat->getIcons();
      }
  }
```

This returned `$cats[a] = array(icon(1), icon(2)` and `$cats[b] = array(icon(1))`

I then tried the following:

```
    $res = array_shift($cats);
    foreach($cats as $cat){
        $res = array_intersect($res, $cat);
    }
```

but got the following error: `Argument #1 is not an array`

I checked the type of `$cat[a]` and `$cat[b]` and they are a Doctrine Persistence Collection

I also tried calling `$res = $res->toArray()` and `$cat = $cat->toArray()` before calling `array_intersect` This resolved the error but did not return the expected results: `Icon(1)`

Does anyone have any thoughts or maybe even a better approach to all of this?

Comment: Why don't you want to use DQL: `... WHERE icon.category in (a, b)` ?

Comment: I tried this for my query: `SELECT i FROM SixStringPearBundle:Icon i WHERE i.categories IN (1, 2)'` and I am getting the following error: `categories IN': Error: Invalid PathExpression. StateFieldPathExpression or SingleValuedAssociationField expected.` The `(1,2)` is referring to the category ids

Comment: `WHERE IDENTITY(i.categories) IN`.

Comment: Would that not return icons that are in ANY of the categories vs icons that are in ALL of the categories?

Comment: Oh sorry misread the question. Then your answer is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the doctrine query builder. It was agonizing but I finally figure it out. Here is the end result:

```
$qb->select('i')
   ->from('SixStringPearBundle:Icon', 'i')
   ->leftJoin('i.categories', 'c')
   ->where('c.name IN (?1)')
   ->groupBy('i.id')
   ->having('count(i.id) = ?2')
   ->setParameters(array(1 => $terms, 2 => count($terms)));
```

Comment: It's better to use placeholder parameters for all inputs.

Comment: Are you talking about: `$qb->orWhere('c.name = \'' . $term . '\'');`? I wasn't sure how to add a placeholder as it is inside of the foreach and there are an unknown number of terms

Comment: That's where you can use `IN`: `$qb->orWhere('c.name IN (?1)')->setParameter(1, $terms); ... ->having('count(i.id) = ?2') ... ` (requires doctrine >= 2.1).

Comment: Worked great thanks! I updated my answer to reflect the proper use of placeholders